# Why doesn't mmc_spi.c allow highmem?

Tags: linux-kernel

I would like to use the Linux mmc_spi on a system with highmem enabled. I can't see why the mmc_spi module won't work with highmem.

The module uses kmap() and kmalloc(), so I am unsure as to why high memory would be a problem.

The Kconfig file indicates that the file depends on !HIGHMEM and the source code has the comment:

> **/* allow pio too; we don't allow highmem */** on line 939.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about kernel programming. Programming questions are off-topic on [unix.se] but can be asked on [so].

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work with highmem? Did you read it somewhere, or did your kernel build crash, or what?

Comment: The Kconfig depends on !HIGHMEM